# Dimensionality reduction estimation

Tags: vectors, expected-value

Assume we have a vector $x\in R^d$ and consider $F(x) = s^Tx$, where $s$ is a $d$-dimensional random vector with entries drawn uniformly and independently from $\{-1,1\}$.
What is the value of $E[F(x)^2]$ ? How can it be formally proved?

Answer (score 0):

Since $s_i^2=1$ while $E[s_is_j]=E[s_i]E[s_j]=0^2=0$ for $i\ne j$,$$F^2=(s_ix_i)^2=s_is_jx_ix_j\implies E[F^2]=\delta_{ij}x_ix_j=x^2.$$

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the first line? Why that expected value is null?

Comment: @bruce_springsteen See edit.